# Element type is invalid - React.js (No solution found on web)

Tags: reactjs, import, compiler-errors, export, element

I've searched for solution last hour and nothing helped. My export and import are correctly defined. I also tried to replace entire contents of Clock.js with another component, and it worked. I'm just going crazy..

```
import React from 'react';

const pad = n => (n < 10 ? `0${n}` : n);
const format = t => `${pad(t.getUTCHours())}:${pad(t.getUTCMinutes())}:${pad(t.getUTCSeconds())}`;

const Clock = ({ lastUpdate, light }) => (
  <div className={light ? 'light' : ''}>
    {format(new Date(lastUpdate))}
    <style jsx>{` 
        div {
          padding: 15px;
          display: inline-block;
          color: #82FA58;
          font: 50px menlo, monaco, monospace;
          background-color: #000;
        }

        .light {
          background-color: #999;
        }
      `}
    </style>
  </div>
);

export default Clock;
```

Import & Call:

```
import Clock from '../components/Clock';
<Clock lastUpdate={lastUpdate} light={light} />
```

Error:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

Clock imported to:
https://pastebin.com/fWRCaYM5

Comment: `<style jsx>` what's that?

Comment: https://github.com/zeit/styled-jsx . Same error without this tag.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the entire `<style jsx> ... </style>`? (that looks like a terrible library that encourages bad practices btw)

Comment: No, same error. As I said earlier.

Comment: Add in the code for your entire component that imported `Clock`. Maybe the error is in that file.

Comment: Done that. When I replace Clock with another component, no error. Everything else is the same. So I think problem is inside Clock. What's even more strange, that this example works perfectly in another project, from which I pasted..

Comment: Does it work if you replace it with `const Clock = () => null`?

Comment: No, same error. React debug even says 'Check your code at layout.jsx:25.'..

Comment: Can you create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on https://codesandbox.io/s/new?

Comment: Yes, it works here.. https://codesandbox.io/s/vn828mvkwl

Comment: Check if you have identical code and package versions on your local machine.

Comment: Nope. Every package is newer in local machine except next, which has version "latest" in the example.

Comment: Well..no one on the internet can fix your problem if it only happens on your machine. Try starting a new project on a new directory and install the dependencies and see if it still happens.

Comment: Or click the download button on the codesandbox link u posted and try run it locally.

Comment: Another problem that may occur is a hidden character inducing a syntax error somewhere in the original code. Those can be a pain in... well you know.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried renaming Clock to something else? There could be some sort of conflict somewhere.

EDIT ---

You can use styles like this:

```
var style = {
    padding: "15px",
    display: "inline-block",
    color: "#82FA58",
    font: "50px menlo, monaco, monospace",
    backgroundColor: light? "#999" : "#000"
};
```

And then use:

```
<div style={style}>
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried it. But it wasn't root of the problem.

Comment: I've updated my answer in response to your new question.

Comment: Yeah, that's inline styles. What about className definition and then reuse like this: `<div className={light ? 'light' : ''}` . How can I define .light style?

Comment: You'd need to create `.light{background-color: #999};` in your style sheet. Alternatively use the ternary operator within the style in my suggestion.

Comment: I've decided to use SCSS with modules. Look sexy: `import scss from '../static/styles.scss';  className={scss.serverClock}`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by removing styled jsx. I didn't get it to work, even by reading through instructions with NPM module and babel config.

Webpack was using HMR, so error didn't go away without restarting build.

I am using inline styles now. I would like to get suggestions writing className styles for React component. Anyone?